# Использование тега <link> внутри тега <body>

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, файлы, синтаксис

Можно ли подключать css файлы внутри тела страницы, а не в его head?

Comment: а почему бы и нет?

Comment: @Grundy ну я такого не видел ни где, просто html лояльно к ошибкам относится и может по этому такое возможно.

Comment: Да , можно , но нужно ли...

Comment: Всякие оптимизаторы загрузки страниц советуют в верхней части загружать немного самого важного css, а остальные стили - где-то поближе к закрывающемуся `body`. Так что подключайте на здоровье.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В HTML4.1 это было запрещено, но в HTML5 данное ограничение убрали.

Comment: _____благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее интересный эффект от стилей внутри `<body>` — это то, что для такого размещения в браузерах планируется (а в Хроме Канари уже есть) убрать блокирование рендера этими ресурсами. Т. е., когда стили находятся в `<head>` они являются блокирующим рендер ресурсом, без скачивания и разбора которого браузер не начнет отрисовку. А когда это поведение станет одинаковым во всех браузерах, у нас фактически появится аналог атрибута `async` для скриптов. А когда HTTP/2 станет стандартом, то и по поводу раздельных файлов можно будет перестать париться :-)

Answer (score 1):

Проверил на  [https://validator.w3.org/](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea), ответ валидатора добавил картинкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]